# Pizza slice shape using GD Image?

Tags: php, gd

I need to "transform" a normal rectangle image into a "pizze slice". So this:

[image]

Must be stretched into this:

[image]

This way I lose the actual wording, so it's not 100% correct. I need it to not just mask those parts, but also "stretch" the slice so it will fit into the new triangle shape, so none of the text is lost.

My photoshopping skills are so limited, I can't even do a proper preview in photoshop that shows how it must be cut.

How would I do this using GD Image?

Comment: can you please send me the code using jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get the job done - the script is commented, so you should have no trouble understanding it.

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 130);
$text = "Text that can be\nwrapped to next line";

//draw red background
imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, imagesx($img), imagesy($img), 0xa00000);

//draw green text
putenv('GDFONTPATH=/usr/share/fonts/TTF');
imagettftext($img, 40, 0, 20, 50, 0x00a000, 'arial.ttf', $text);

//stretch whole thing vertically
$img = imagescale($img, imagesx($img), imagesy($img) * 2);

//compute pizza transformation
$y_arr = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); $x++)
{
    //compute simple "triangle" shape
    $linear_y = $x * imagesy($img) / 2 / imagesx($img);
    //get some variations with cos()
    $cos_y = cos($x * 2 * M_PI / imagesx($img));
    $cos_y *= cos($x * 2 * M_PI / imagesx($img) / 2);
    $cos_y = (1 - $cos_y) * imagesy($img) / 4;
    //finally combine these two
    $y = ($cos_y + $linear_y * 2) / 3;
    //and push the coordinate onto stack
    $y_arr []= $y;
}

//create target image
$dstimg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($img), imagesy($img));

//scale each column according to pizza transformation
foreach ($y_arr as $x => $y)
    imagecopyresized($dstimg, $img, $x, $y, $x, 0, 1, max(1, imagesy($img) - 2 * $y), 1, imagesy($img) - 1);

//write the image to PNG file
imagepng($dstimg, 'test.png');
```

Result:

[image: pizza]

Comment: Your problem actually writes the text. I should've given an image that had no text as the problem is specifically with an image that already has text on it. Can you maybe adjust your answer? I will definitely mark it correct then.

Comment: ? This will work for any `$img`, provided you draw what you want to it first.

Comment: p.s. only problem i still have is that I am losing transparency .

Comment: In that case, check out `imagesavealpha` and `imagealphablending` functions + other questions here on SO.